# One SPEC file to support multiple architectures

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I'm modifying a RPM SPEC file to build for a x86_64 architecture.  The existing SPEC includes a package applicable to 32-bit only, i.e. `Requires: package-x-y-z`.  How do I remove the `package-x-y-z` requirement *just* for the x86_64 architecture, while still requiring the other OS to use it?

I tried using `%ifnarch x86_64` before the `Requires: package x-y-z` line but was unsuccessful.

I could make separate SPEC files, but ideally this one SPEC file would support both architectures for better maintainability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you happen to be using `BuildArch` as well in your spec-file?

I have just tested this on a **x86_64** build machine with a spec file where

```
BuildArch: noarch
```

and indeed

```
%ifnarch x86_64
Requires: package-x-y-z
%endif
```

produced a package that did require package-x-y-z...

Since my spec file produces a noarch package, I tried changing the logic; and

```
%ifnarch noarch
Requires: package-x-y-z
%endif
```

produced a package that did **not** depend on package-x-y-z.

### Conclusion

If you use **BuildArch**, then the macros `ifarch` and `ifnarch` will match wrt that architecture and not your real build-machine architecture.

Comment: `BuildArch: noarch` was indeed the culprit.  Removed it and `%ifnarch` works smoothly.